# Calcular preço por minuto

Tags: php, time

Preciso realizar o cálculo de preço a partir de uma hora inicial, por exemplo os primeiros 30 minutos após a entrada custa fixo R$30, após esse período cada minuto precisa somar R$1,50:

- 30 minutos = R$30,00
- Minuto adicional = R$1,50

Entrada: 10:00
Saída: 10:45

**Preço a pagar: R$52,50**

Para realizar a contagem do minuto a partir da hora de entrada, estou usando o código:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$dataLocal = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');                       

$data1 = $play_hentrada;
$data2 = $dataLocal;
                             
$unix_data1 = strtotime($data1);
$unix_data2 = strtotime($data2);
                             
                             
$nHoras   = ($unix_data2 - $unix_data1) / (60 * 60);
$nMinutos = (($unix_data2 - $unix_data1) % (60 * 60)) / 60;
                             
printf('%02d:%02d', $nHoras, $nMinutos);
```

tentei realizar o cálculo assim:

```
//VALOR MINUTO
$valor_minuto = 1.50;

//TOTAL HORA
$nHoras = number_format($nHoras, 0, '.', '');

//TOTAL MINUTO
$nMinutos = number_format($nMinutos, 2, '.', '');

//TOTAL MINUTOS
$total_minutos = ($nHoras * 60) + $nMinutos;

if($total_minutos < 30){
    $total_sem_minimo = 0;
}else{
    $total_sem_minimo = $total_minutos - 30;
}

$total_total = $total_sem_minimo * $valor_minuto;

$total = $total_total + 30;

$total = number_format($total, 2, '.', '');

echo $total;
```

Comment: Basta calcular a diferença em minutos entre o horário de entrada e o horário de saída. Subtraia 30 deste valor, para descontar os 30 minutos iniciais, somando R$ ao total; os minutos restantes você multiplica por 1,5 e soma o resultado no total.

Comment: Não consegui realizar esse cálculo, ainda to aprendendo a linguagem :/

Comment: Como tentou fazer?

Comment: editei como eu tentei realizar o código

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro você precisa calcular a duração total em minutos. Depois, basta ver se a duração passou de 30 minutos. Se não passou, o valor total é $30, e se passou, subtraia 30 minutos do total, e o que sobrar você multiplica por `1.5`:

```php
function toMins($horario) {
    list($h, $m) = explode(':', $horario);
    return $h * 60 + $m;
}


$entrada = '10:00';
$saida = '10:45';
$minuto_adicional = 1.5;
$total_minutos = toMins($saida) - toMins($entrada);

if ($total_minutos <= 0) {
    // só por "garantia", verificar se o valor não deu zero ou negativo
    // imprime alguma mensagem de erro, ou não faz nada, vc que sabe
    echo "O horário de entrada é maior ou igual ao de saída";
} else {
    // se entrou nesse else, é porque ficou pelo menos 1 minuto
    // então já paga $30, que é o valor pelos primeiros 30 minutos
    $pagar = 30;
    if ($total_minutos > 30) { // se passou de 30 minutos, cobrar os minutos excedentes
        $pagar += ($total_minutos - 30) * $minuto_adicional;
    }

    $h = floor($total_minutos / 60);
    $m = $total_minutos % 60;
    printf("duração: %02d:%02d\nTotal a pagar: R$%s\n", $h, $m, number_format($pagar, 2, ','));
}
```

Usei `number_format` para formatar com duas casas decimais e vírgula como separador decimal. A saída será:

```
duração: 00:45
Total a pagar: R$52,50
```

Claro, estou assumindo que o horário só tem horas e minutos, e que sempre se referem ao mesmo dia (não haverá, por exemplo, entrada às 23:00 e saída às 02:00 do dia seguinte).

---

Vale lembrar também que `number_format` retorna uma string formatada. Claro que se a string estiver no formato "correto", o PHP pode fazer a coerção automática de tipos, mas de forma geral, se vai fazer cálculos, prefira não transformar o número em string.

---

Outra forma de obter o total de minutos é usando [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```php
$total_minutos = ((new DateTime($saida))->getTimestamp() - (new DateTime($entrada))->getTimestamp()) / 60;
```

O restante do código é igual. **Mas tem um porém**: quando a string só tem o horário, o `DateTime` usa a data atual e o timezone que estiver configurado no PHP (no seu caso, você está setando explicitamente para `America/Sao_Paulo` - que corresponde ao Horário de Brasília).

Na maioria dos casos não dá problema, mas se rodar em uma data em que ocorre mudança de horário de verão, pode dar diferenças. Por exemplo, quando o horário de verão acaba, à meia-noite o relógio é atrasado para 23:00, ou seja, todos os minutos entre 23:00 e 23:59 ocorrem duas vezes (uma no horário de verão e outra no horário normal). Se tiver algum intervalo de horas entre 23:00 e 23:59, você tem que saber a qual se refere - e neste caso somente a hora e minuto não é o suficiente para fazer o cálculo correto. Mas talvez já esteja fugindo demais do escopo da pergunta...

Outra diferença é que o `DateTime` dá erro se o horário for inválido (por exemplo, se for `25:00`). Já usando o primeiro código, a validação teria que ser feita manualmente, algo como:

```php
function toMins($horario) {
    list($h, $m) = explode(':', $horario);
    if ($h < 0 || $h > 24) {
        // hora inválida (dar erro, mostrar mensagem, etc)
    }
    if ($m < 0 || $m > 60) {
        // minuto inválido (dar erro, mostrar mensagem, etc)
    }
    return $h * 60 + $m;
}
```

---

Enfim, aritmética de datas/horas é mais complicado do que parece, cheio de *corner cases* que podem ou não ser relevantes conforme o contexto. Se suas entradas são controladas (por exemplo, a entrada e saída sempre são "hora:minuto" do mesmo dia), uma abordagem mais simples não traz problemas. Mas se podem ter horários em dias diferentes, fusos horários, entradas inválidas, etc, aí vai ficando mais complicado, exigindo controles adicionais (como não ficou claro se é esse o caso, vou me ater a apenas mencionar que esse tipo de coisa pode acontecer, e nesses casos devem ser levadas em consideração).

Comment: +1 pelo post porém para cálculo dos minutos eu recomendaria o uso da classe Datetime + exemplos desse post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365191/how-to-get-time-difference-in-minutes-in-php

Comment: @MarcosXavier Atualizei a resposta

Comment: Boa. Até funciona no seu primeiro exemplo mas vai que por alguma motivo enviem ex. 24:61 como horário. Possivelmente daria algum bug ou erro de cálculo no fluxo.

Comment: @MarcosXavier Nesse caso o `DateTime` dá erro, e o cálculo manual aceita (embora não devesse). Atualizei novamente a resposta com esse detalhe.